# React registerServiceWorker- install event

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I am working on React web app and to deployed it I used `create-react-app`. There is a file called `registerServiceWorker.js` which takes care of initializing the `service worker`. I want to cache some files on `install` event however the `self.addEventListener('install', event` gives me the error "Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals". I manage to get rid of that by changing self to window, however the install event is never being fired. How to use this "build in" service worker in React? Or can I create the other service worker?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? The only answer here is not helpful to me, I already have my own service worker file. But I cannot get the install event to fire.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this myself, I finally figured out the following pieces of information:

the `serviceWorker.js` file in the default CRA project is ***not*** the same sort of `service-worker.js` file described by the PWA documentation from [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). That's not where the `self.addEventListener` statements go. They go into the file *referenced* by CRA's serviceWorker.js, specified by the string

```
const `swUrl = ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`
```

By default, that `service-worker.js` is a file that you cannot access or modify! You will need to create your own service-worker.js file in the `/public` folder and point `swUrl` to it instead. It should point to the location as a string, statically, which means it will not get integrated as part of the build process and `self` will correctly refer to the module instead of the global context.

Answer (score -1):

I found the simple solution. This utility is perfect for that: https://github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw.

> cra-append-sw
>
> Utility tool to append custom code to ServiceWorker created by Create
>   React App.
>
> It allows to keep the default CRA configuration (no ejecting). It
>   simply appends custom code to the ServiceWorker file created by CRA
>   build scripts. By default, it bundles the code using very basic
>   Webpack+Babel configuration (this can be omitted; see options).
>
> Installation
>
> $ npm install cra-append-sw --save
>
> Usage
>
> "start": "react-scripts start && cra-append-sw --mode dev
>   ./custom-sw.js",
>
> "build": "react-scripts build && cra-append-sw
>   ./custom-sw.js",